# Apache Kafka ProducerConfig internal.auto.downgrade.txn.commit isn't a known config

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm not sure how to title this issue. But we have a Kafka producer project which has this warning show up on the logs.

```
o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig : The configuration 'internal.auto.downgrade.txn.commit' was supplied but isn't a known config.
```

We are using this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

In our pom.xml we have this for spring configs:

```
spring: 
  metrics:
    export:
      delay-millis: 10500
  kafka:
    producer:
      retries: 10
      buffer-memory: 33554432
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          toInboundKafkaTopic-out-0:
            producer:
              configuration:
                key:
                  serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        binder:
          requiredAcks: all
          brokers: (removed)
      bindings:
        toInboundKafkaTopic-out-0: 
          destination: OutboundSink
          content-type: application/json
      source: toInboundKafkaTopic
```

The main question is how can we resolve the warning message in the logs?

Comment: You can generally ignore it. Which version(s) are you using (spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka, kafka-clients)?

Comment: Not sure the specific version, but we are using version 2020.0.3 on the spring-cloud-dependencies artifact. Is there any documentation on how to silence these warnings on our logs?

Answer (score 0):

I need to know the versions I asked for in the comment, because it sounds like you might have some mis-matches.

I just built a new project with 2020.0.5 which gets spring-kafka 2.7.12 with kafka-clients 2.7.2, and I don't get that message; I only get it if I change the kafka-clients to 2.8.1. You should really let Boot manage the versions for you so all the versions are aligned.

Either switch the kafka-clients back to 2.7.2 or upgrade spring-kafka to 2.8.4.